# I want to update single value in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

i have use RecyclerView and Adapter and inflte item_list of adapter, each row has one like button and text that store likes value i want to update value when user click like button.

[image]

[image: here is my firebase database structure][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdyv5.png)

Comment: Sounds great. Can you add your code, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be better if you have post your adapter's code.
But lets assume that you are displaying current likes of each quote besides that like button.

So get the value of current like from your adapter's item and increment it by 1.

Then you need to call this :

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("QuoteList").child("Quote");
mDatabase.child("likes").setValue(mItem.totalLikes + 1);
```

**OR**

You can fetch current values from firebase and update it something like this:

```
 DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("QuoteList").child("Quote").child("likes");
        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long totalLikes =(long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                mDatabase.setValue(totalLikes + 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Just curious, in your example you have `child("likes")` in hand, so why use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of the regular `addValueEventListener`? What's the difference?